# How to display sum of value in bar chart (Kendo angular 4)

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

I need to display sum value at top of the bar chart, using kendo angular bar chart component. Please help on this.

Below is the template code to render bar chart.

```
            <kendo-chart-legend position="vertical" orientation="vertical"></kendo-chart-legend>
            <!--kendo-chart-tooltip format="{0}"></kendo-chart-tooltip-->
            <cst-chart-series>
                <kendo-chart-series-item type="bar" [stack]="true" *ngFor="let item of series2" type="column"  [data]="item.amount" [name]="item.name">
                    <kendo-chart-series-item-labels [content]="labelContent" color="white" position="center" background="none">
                        <kendo-chart-series-item-tooltip>
                            <ng-template let-value = "value" >
                                {{value > 0 ? (value | number:'.'+(selectedDecimalPosition ? selectedDecimalPosition : 0)+'-'+(selectedDecimalPosition ? selectedDecimalPosition : 0)) : ''}}
                            </ng-template>
                        </kendo-chart-series-item-tooltip>
                    </kendo-chart-series-item-labels>
                </kendo-chart-series-item>
            </kendo-chart-series>
        </kendo-chart>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlaKh.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Should be possible to achieve this with an additional series and custom label content that shows the stack value:

```
//series
<kendo-chart-series-item *ngFor="let item of series2" ...>
</kendo-chart-series-item>

//total series
<kendo-chart-series-item 
    type="column" [data]="totalSeriesData" [labels]="{ visible: true, content: totalLabelContent  }">
</kendo-chart-series-item>

// component
public totalSeriesData: any[] = [];

public totalLabelContent(args: any): string {
  return args.stackValue;
}

constructor() {
  const totalLength = this.series2.reduce((acc, item) => Math.max(item.amount.length, acc), 0);
  for(let idx = 0; idx < totalLength; idx++) {
    this.totalSeriesData.push(0);
  }
}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/9SF7d1YCud5qPRWvgB65?p=preview

Comment: Thank you so much @SiliconSoul